# LED Driver with "Common cathode"

Tags: led

I'm in the process of building a lamp. It is about a
Pendant lamp in which a coaxial cable with an outer braid is used for the power supply in order to swing the light objects (5 pendulums). In the light objects there are LED modules that require CC with 700mA. This connects the GND of all 5 constant current sources in the canopy of the lamp is the idea. I am therefore looking for an LED driver (or an LED driver IC) that can handle common cathodes. The luminous objects should each have their own KSQ. Do you know something suitable? Maybe even a circuit diagram?

If you want to understand more this is the concrete setup:
It is a pendant lamp, the pendulums are on one
Suspended steel cable. In addition, a coaxial cable with a copper braid on the outside and an insulated conductor on the inside leads to each pendulum. The pendulums each have built-in LED modules which require a constant current of 700mA / approx. 14.8V. Each pendulum should have its own KSQ. But since there is a connection to the canopy due to the suspension of the pendulum by the coaxial cable and its screen (which should act as a negative pole), I need a KSQ which works with a common cathode. Because ultimately all Vout- the individual KSQ's have a connection to each other via the metal canopy.

[image]

Comment: What is a "KSQ"? What difference does "common cathode" make? Note that shopping questions will result in having your question closed so you might want to quickly remove that bit and ask a technical question instead.

Comment: You can not use constant current driver to feed LEDs connected in parallel, only in series.

Comment: You can use a voltage source even PWM for dimming but you then need to add balancing resistors in each LED circuit.  1.5 Ohm with a 16V supply would give you about what you need however you will have about 3.5 watts to get rid of at full brightness.  What is a KSQ? There are constant current drivers available on the commercial market doing exactly what you want. However it would take five of them, I did not look for multiples.

Comment: Ahh sorry KSQ is german and means Constant Current Source.... hmm but driving leds with a resistor is not that efficient or?

Comment: Generally driving power LEDs with resistors is a horrible idea.  \$I^2R\$ determines the losses, so for small current indicator LEDs with small voltage overhead, losses can be negligible, but at 700mA losses become significant.  The resistor must drop enough voltage to heat itself enough(can be partially heated by the LEDs too) that the PTC(Positive temperature coefficient) of the resistor cancels out the NTC(Negative temperature coefficient) of the LEDs to prevent them from going into thermal runaway.

Comment: This is a pain in the butt to calculate, so my personal preference is just to spend a few extra bucks on a current regulator for power LEDs.  You might want to check out 700mA Luxeon Buckpuck LED drivers.  They have decent efficiency, they're ultra small, potted, and they only require 2.5V overhead(which is not fully wasted because they are a switching regulator).  They're about 10 bucks a pop, but for a setup like yours where you need 5 drivers for 5 series strings, they're the most set and forget thing I've found.